# bluestore(/var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-2/block) _read_bdev_label failed to open /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-2/block: (1) Operation not permitted

Tags: ceph

When I have upgrade the from Octopus 15.2.10 to Pacific 16.2.0, the mon nodes starts successfully using the manual upgrade process (by installing the packages with no orch)
however when I have upgrade the OSDs, the ceph-osd service does not start.
It worth mentioning that I have used the Ubutntu Focal Ceph package for upgrading (no orch)
[image]

it worth mentioning that when I issue the "/usr/bin/ceph-osd -f --cluster ceph --id 2 --setuser ceph --setgroup ceph", it starts successfully joins to the cluster

here is the ceph-osd.log message:
[image]

set uid:gid to 64045:64045 (ceph:ceph)
ceph version 16.2.0 (0c2054e95bcd9b30fdd908a79ac1d8bbc3394442) pacific (stable), process ceph-osd, pid 1974
pidfile_write: ignore empty --pid-file
bluestore(/var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-2/block) _read_bdev_label failed to open /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-2/block: (1) Operation not permitted
** ERROR: unable to open OSD superblock on /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-2: (2) No such file or directory

any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ceph-osd@.service Failed with ProtectClock=true, see

- https://github.com/ceph/ceph/pull/40845